# Reverse complement of reconstruction model for assembling reads

Tags: models, bioinformatics, sequences

One way to assemble fragments produced by DNA sequencing (often called reads) is to seek for the shortest common superstring that contains all the reads of a given set of reads. One model for this problem is the reconstruction model, which calculates the minimal edit distance between a possible superstring (that contains all fragments) and each one of the fragments. What I don't understand yet is the fact that when calculating the edit distance for a given fragment, it's necessary to calculate the edit distance for the reverse complement of that fragment.
An example of a fragment and its reverse complement could be:
ACTGTCC fragment
TGACAGG complement (the complementary strand as we know)
GGACAGT reverse complement
According to the book I'm reading the ideia behind it is to find a superstring as short as possible that either the given fragment or its reverse complement must be an approximate substring of the superstring. I know that many mathematical/computational models don't have a biological sense for their way of soluting a biological problem, but this recontruction model I could think it's biologically reasonable to find a string that contains all the fragments of a certain region of a DNA sequence, and all the complement fragments, after all when assembling we can find both strand sequence. But a reverse complement is not something that exist for a given sequence, unless it has suffered some kind of break-recombination event, which is something not expected, mainly when talking about conserved regions. Do you any idea why this model takes into account the reverse complements ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should ask biostars: http://www.biostars.org/